# Python assignment with optional result if not found

Tags: python

I want to do an assignment which defaults to another if it fails.

```
this = {'one':1}
test = this['a'] if this['a'] else "Wololo"
```

I get a `KeyError` when I try this. Reason I need a one liner assignment is I have a minimum of five characters which may be in the dictionary and that requires five separate try blocks to check without returning an error.

Comment: Check `defaultdict`.

Comment: `.get` is the real answer, but note that the ternary version would work if you made it `this['a'] if 'a' in this else ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.get` and pass a default value, if the key doesn't exist then the default value is returned:

```
In [267]:
this = {'one':1}
this.get('a','Wololo')

Out[267]:
'Wololo'
```

Comment: And if you didn't select the second argument, it will return `None` instead a `KeyError` :)